# rtl8188ee make errors on 13.04 (L75D-A7280)

Tags: installation, wireless, drivers, 13.04, toshiba-satellite

I'm trying to setup my wifi on a fresh 13.04 install on a Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280.

I'm still a linux noob, so I may have gone down the rabbit hole, but I've made it this far:

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:hAk00I57NH4J:ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php%3Ft%3D2162026+RTL8188EE+ubuntu+wireless&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=browser-ubuntu

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:X64AZzPqfMcJ:ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php%3Ft%3D2146803+&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=us&client=ubuntu

I've edited `pci.h` as recommended, but I'm still getting this on `make`:

```
make -C /lib/modules/3.8.0-19-generic/build M=/home/trevor/Downloads/realtek modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
  CC [M]  /home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/base.o
In file included from /home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/base.c:39:0:
/home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/pci.h:30:1: error: unknown type name ‘fndef’
/home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/pci.h:33:2: error: #endif without #if
In file included from include/linux/pci.h:20:0,
                 from /home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/pci.h:39,
                 from /home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/base.c:39:
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:12:1: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘typedef’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:21:2: error: unknown type name ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:36:2: error: unknown type name ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:37:33: error: ‘kernel_ulong_t’ undeclared here (not in a function)
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:37:3: error: requested alignment is not an integer constant
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:125:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:151:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:164:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:178:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:189:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:197:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:205:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:210:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:275:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:324:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:351:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:376:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:423:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:443:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:454:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:518:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:550:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:561:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
include/linux/mod_devicetable.h:592:2: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before ‘kernel_ulong_t’
make[2]: *** [/home/trevor/Downloads/realtek/base.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/trevor/Downloads/realtek] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-19-generic'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How can I get my wireless working?

**`lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"`**

```
05:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0181]
```

**wired connection working**

I am happily connected and talking to the world on my first ubuntu lappie via the wired connection.  I do not know what driver it's using.  13.04 saw it during installation.

Comment: What exact hardware are we talking about here? Please provide the exact output of `lspci -nnk | grep -iEA3 "(wireless|network)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Forget about patching.

From [comment #36](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1096989/comments/36) in [LP bug #1096989](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1096989) it is reported that the stable Linux 3.10 kernel has gained support for your Wireless LAN device. Yes, this is about a Lenovo Ideapad device, but that doesn't matter as it contains the very same Wireless LAN card you have (identified by the numerical id's).

Here's how to install a mainline kernel: [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/q/119080/88802) and pick the 3.10.1 (now latest stable kernel): http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v3.10.1-saucy/

But really, **watch this bug report** and remove the kernel once this is fixed in Ubuntu stable release kernel. By installing a mainline kernel yourself you won't receive any security updates.

For future visitors: upgrade to the latest stable (non-rc) 3.10+ kernel you see on http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline

Comment: is there any way to install the driver properly without going to saucy?  i cannot install my video driver http://support.amd.com/us/kbarticles/Pages/AMDCatalyst13-6LINBetaDriver.aspx  tyvm!

Comment: @Gracchus It's just the kernel built for saucy. But yeah, your proprietary graphics drivers may not be ready for this release. :( Perhaps an updated `compat-wireless` package can solve this. Let me research this.