# Installing Ubuntu 13.10 'Saucy Salamander' on L75D-A7280 hangs on a black screen

Tags: installation, dual-boot, 13.10, uefi, toshiba-satellite

Trying to get Ubuntu 13.10 to work and it will not. Seen that somebody is having a similar problem, some things failing then it just hangs on a black screen (after pressing F1 to see what it's doing). My system is a Toshiba Satellite L75D-A7280, and I have tried two different files that I had downloaded from Ubuntu.com with no luck.

My laptop came with Windows 8 and following the dual-boot directions Ubuntu 12.04 was installed and worked perfect, except for completely obliterating Windows 8 and voiding my warranty, meaning neither Toshiba nor the retail center I bought my system from can help me legally, besides giving advice... nor can I return it to get a non-UEFI based system.

I really need to figure this out, I am a student and need my laptop working properly with any OS I put on it. Will continue searching for any information I can find.

Comment: where are you in the installation process?  hard to believe that 12.04 worked perfectly since our video drivers are still in beta.  (you were probably looking at my posts)

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to 13.10 *exactly*, but I'm running Ubuntu satisfactorily on the same model with 13.04...and a few extra things.

It's not clear from your current edit where the process is failing, but I was able to boot from USB with 13.04.  From there, I installed normally.

I did not immediately get the black screen, but my wifi didn't work while my ethernet did.

To fix the wifi problem, follow [the checked answer from my question](https://askubuntu.com/a/322737/169736).

Now, the only two things that're missing as far as I'm aware are the battery drivers and video drivers.

Using the technique described in the link above as well as [this to make sure your boot mount isn't clogged](https://askubuntu.com/questions/334976/safe-to-remove-old-kernels-after-installing-latest-mainline), you want to to [use at least kernel 3.10.10](https://askubuntu.com/a/341972/169736) to fix the battery issue (this also made most hotkeys work more correctly).

To install the video drivers, follow [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/288355/128334), ***BUT FIRST BE SURE TO APPLY THE PATCH IN [THE CHECKED ANSWER HERE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/338129/cinnamon-segmentation-fault-with-amd-catalyst-13-8-beta)!!!***  I use [Catalyst 13.8 BETA](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Catalyst-13-8-Beta-Driver-for-LINUX.aspx), but BETA2 is out; however, BETA2 still requires the patch.

I haven't tried to upgrade to 13.10 myself because I'm running cinnamon, and I'd heard there were many problems, but my guess is that upgrading to 13.10 from 13.04 with only the changes above should be ok.

If not, I'm sure another answer can help with that part (or I'll be back when I have the time to attempt a failed upgrade reinstall).

Answer (score 0):

> My laptop came with Windows 8 and following the dual-boot directions Ubuntu 12.04 was installed and worked perfect, except for completely obliterating Windows 8 and voiding my warranty, meaning neither Toshiba nor the retail center I bought my system from can help me legally

I wouldn't take any claim that installing Linux voids a warranty sitting down. At a minimum, I'd read the warranty myself, and possibly consult an attorney on the matter. On cursory inspection, the 1-year Toshiba warranty [here](http://support.toshiba.com/warranty) does not cover software, but also does not explicitly say that use of third-party software voids any other aspect of the warranty. I am most definitely *not* an attorney, but I do know that there are laws that prohibit warranties from being voided for using third-party products (such as third-party oil filters in cars), and it's entirely possible that such a law would apply to third-party software in computers. Of course, you might not want to sue Toshiba over the matter, but if they're denying a warranty claim, the mere *threat* of a lawsuit might cause them to cave in. Furthermore, I've heard many tales of retail clerks who make ridiculous and erroneous claims to the effect that installing Software X will void a computer's warranty. When called on this, the clerks are invariably proven wrong by manufacturers' agents who actually know what they're talking about.

> nor can I return it to get a non-UEFI based system.

These days, there are few or no non-EFI systems being sold, so even if you return the computer, you'll have to exchange it for another EFI-based system.

The problem you're experiencing can almost certainly be resolved without resorting to the warranty; however, it's unclear precisely what your problem is. If Windows was truly overwritten, you'll need to obtain a Windows recovery disc -- at least, assuming you want Windows installed on the computer. You can probably buy such a disc from Toshiba. (Manufacturers have gotten extraordinarily cheap; they no longer ship recovery media with their computers.) Alternatively, see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/493766/where-can-i-download-windows-8-legally-from-microsoft) for options on obtaining legal copies online.

It's entirely possible that Windows has not been overwritten, though; it could be that it's just a question of the Windows boot loader being overwritten or not being launched from GRUB. In this case, you might need to run a Windows recovery disc to restore the boot loader, or simply reconfigure GRUB.

If you don't care about Windows and just want to get Ubuntu up and running, there are numerous questions on this site that cover this topic, such as [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/208405/how-to-efi-install-ubuntu) and [this one.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/302680/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-alongside-uefi-enabled-windows-8-on-a-dell-xps-8500) There are also lots of pages outside of this site that cover this topic, such as [this one that I wrote.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)

In any event, more information is needed before more specific advice can be given. I recommend you run the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) from Linux. (Use a live CD, if necessary.) This will produce a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to a [pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL that it spits out here. That will give us more details about your setup.